# sld styles library

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am looking for a library with several sld styles that I can add to my geoserver styles directory. I find the default styles provided very limited and do not want to spend to much time with creating new styles, so I think there must be a free collection available.

Comment: what sort of data would you like to style?

Comment: mostly polygons

Comment: polygons of what?

Comment: do you mean what they represent? trees, roads, buildings - anything that can displayed on a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will find a generic collection of styles available on the internet, since non trivial styles are based on source data attributes, which change by name, type and meaning across similar datasets (e.g., a set of address points could have a single address field with everything, or three fields with a road type, road name, civic number and eventual apartment/block letter).

If you are focusing on a specific dataset, e.g., OSM, you might find something around on the net, but even in that case, whether it's going to be usable or not depends on how the OSM raw data has been transformed into a local database (e..g, one giant table for lines, or many classified among roads, rivers and the like?)